# What does 「生き残る目」 mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage

I came across this sentence while reading [下町ロケット](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8B%E7%94%BA%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%88).

> 「ウチで密かに調べてみましたが、佃製作所はいま、資金調達すらままならない苦境にあるそうです。どう転んだところで、佃製作所に**生き残る目**はありませんよ。それにですねーーー」

The most obvious interpretation for me was,

> We searched from our end and Tsukuda Works is having problems raising funds right now. No matter how it turns out, Tsukuda Works **has no way to survive/get out of this.** And ...

I am confused as to what exactly 生き残る目 means here. Some of the possibilities that I can think of

1. 目 symbolizes an essential part of the body, kind of like saying "he will have no limb to use". So, 生き残る目 would kind of symbolize how it would be very difficult to survive when there is nothing to rely on.
2. 目 might symbolize a person. And consequently, 生き残る目 would mean, no person would survive this or, help them out but I am less sure of this than the first one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [目]{め} means "chance" "possibility". According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> め【目】
> ⑩ 好ましいことが起こる可能性。
> 「全員に優勝の**目**が残っている」

I think it's the 目 in the phrase 「[[勝]{か}ち[目]{め}](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%8B%9D%E3%81%A1%E7%9B%AE/#je-12650)がある・ない」.

Another example from [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E7%9B%AE/#je-74309):

> 目がない 3〔可能性がない〕
> この試合では、もう勝利の**目**が無くなった
> There's no longer any chance of our winning the game.

Comment: 「さいころの目」の目　の仲間の用法かなという気もちょっとします．

Comment: 私もそんな気がします。語源はたぶんそれかな、と。